# Display distribution list with aliases

Tags: csv, parsing, awk

I want to make .csv file with distribution lists (and aliases) and its members. My input looks like below

```
# distributionList zimbradladmins@example.com memberCount=0
zimbraMailAlias: zimbradladmins@example.com
zimbraMailAlias: admins@example.com

# distributionList monitoring@example.com memberCount=3
zimbraMailAlias: monitoring@example.com
zimbraMailAlias: monitor@example.com
zimbraMailAlias: monit@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Eatable@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Boorish@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Flawless@example.com

# distributionList all@example.com memberCount=10
zimbraMailAlias: all@example.com
zimbraMailAlias: everyone@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Legal@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Joyous@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: helpdesk@special.example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Crazy@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: Successful@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: operator@special.example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: pawelm@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: tomaszb@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: wojciech@example.com
zimbraMailForwardingAddress: wojtekb@example.com
```

My awk code looks like below

```
BEGIN              { FS=":? " ; print "distributionList,member" }
/memberCount=0/    { print $3,"" }
/^# distributionList / { alias = $3 }
$1=="zimbraMailForwardingAddress" { print(alias,$2 ) }
{OFS=","}
```

And my output:

```
distributionList,member
zimbradladmins@example.com 
monitoring@example.com,Eatable@example.com
monitoring@example.com,Boorish@example.com
monitoring@example.com,Flawless@example.com
all@example.com,Legal@example.com
all@example.com,Joyous@example.com
all@example.com,helpdesk@special.example.com
all@example.com,Crazy@example.com
all@example.com,Successful@example.com
all@example.com,operator@special.example.com
all@example.com,pawelm@example.com
all@example.com,tomaszb@example.com
all@example.com,wojciech@example.com
all@example.com,wojtekb@example.com
```

As you can see I display only distribution group names (zimbradladmins@example.com, monitoring@example.com and all@example.com) and its members. I want to display all zimbraMailAlias for each distribution list and its members.
Final output for above data should be (if no members then display nothing after comma):

```
zimbradladmins@example.com,
admins@example.com,
monitoring@example.com,Eatable@example.com
monitoring@example.com,Boorish@example.com
monitoring@example.com,Flawless@example.com
monitor@example.com,Eatable@example.com
monitor@example.com,Boorish@example.com
monitor@example.com,Flawless@example.com
monit@example.com,Eatable@example.com
monit@example.com,Boorish@example.com
monit@example.com,Flawless@example.com
all@example.com,Legal@example.com
all@example.com,Joyous@example.com
all@example.com,helpdesk@special.example.com
all@example.com,Crazy@example.com
all@example.com,Successful@example.com
all@example.com,operator@special.example.com
all@example.com,pawelm@example.com
all@example.com,tomaszb@example.com
all@example.com,wojciech@example.com
all@example.com,wojtek@example.com
everyone@example.com,Legal@example.com
everyone@example.com,Joyous@example.com
everyone@example.com,helpdesk@special.example.com
everyone@example.com,Crazy@example.com
everyone@example.com,Successful@example.com
everyone@example.com,operator@special.example.com
everyone@example.com,pawelm@example.com
everyone@example.com,tomaszb@example.com
everyone@example.com,wojciech@example.com
everyone@example.com,wojtek@example.com
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Fixed by adding monit@example.com to expected output.

Comment: OK I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=": "; OFS="," }
$1 == "zimbraMailAlias"             { aliases[++numAliases] = $2 }
$1 == "zimbraMailForwardingAddress" { forwards[++numForwards] = $2 }
!NF { prt() }
END { prt() }

function prt(   aliasNr, alias, forwardNr, forward ) {
    for ( aliasNr=1; aliasNr<=numAliases; aliasNr++ ) {
        alias = aliases[aliasNr]
        if ( numForwards == 0 ) {
            print alias, ""
        }
        for ( forwardNr=1; forwardNr<=numForwards; forwardNr++ ) {
            forward = forwards[forwardNr]
            print alias, forward
        }
    }
    delete aliases
    delete forwards
    numAliases = numForwards = 0
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
zimbradladmins@example.com,
admins@example.com,
monitoring@example.com,Eatable@example.com
monitoring@example.com,Boorish@example.com
monitoring@example.com,Flawless@example.com
monitor@example.com,Eatable@example.com
monitor@example.com,Boorish@example.com
monitor@example.com,Flawless@example.com
monit@example.com,Eatable@example.com
monit@example.com,Boorish@example.com
monit@example.com,Flawless@example.com
all@example.com,Legal@example.com
all@example.com,Joyous@example.com
all@example.com,helpdesk@special.example.com
all@example.com,Crazy@example.com
all@example.com,Successful@example.com
all@example.com,operator@special.example.com
all@example.com,pawelm@example.com
all@example.com,tomaszb@example.com
all@example.com,wojciech@example.com
all@example.com,wojtekb@example.com
everyone@example.com,Legal@example.com
everyone@example.com,Joyous@example.com
everyone@example.com,helpdesk@special.example.com
everyone@example.com,Crazy@example.com
everyone@example.com,Successful@example.com
everyone@example.com,operator@special.example.com
everyone@example.com,pawelm@example.com
everyone@example.com,tomaszb@example.com
everyone@example.com,wojciech@example.com
everyone@example.com,wojtekb@example.com
```

Comment: Wow, the script works like a charm! You did amazing thing for me that I appreciate very much! It's perfect and I have no words... I don't know how to thank you but... Thank You :) All the best for You and for your loved ones. Take care! ;)